# Filtering the profile feed fetched from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the profile feed from a user's facebook. For this I am using the graph api and calling the feed api to fetch the data. But I want only those things posted by his friends. However, I am getting also the posts of his pictures(like the 5 pictures in a row at the top of the profile page) which we can see in the new facebook layout. How can I filter this while calling the feed api so that only the posts by others can be fetched?

Comment: You need to use FQL I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample of what facebook returns:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1000011715XXXXX_5006082821985",
         "from": {
            "name": "test",
            "id": "10000117XXXXXX"
         },...
```

You need the from attribute. That id is the id of the person who posted on the wall. If it's the same with the user id you are querying you can filter it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello DannyKK. Actually I can filter it after my application fetches the data from facebook. But I want to call the graph api such that the api itself provides me filtered data. Is it possible with some parameter or something while calling the facebook api

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. What you want to do is impossible with the graph api, you'll need to use FQL. Specifically, you can query the stream table, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/, and filter it with the source_id column. Good luck